# How to add Class name to Angular2 directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I wish to add a class name to NG2 directive in order to apply CSS rules on it. Given the following component:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'search-form',
  templateUrl: 'search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'search-form.component.css']
})
```

I tried this:

```
search-form {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

But it did not work.

How can I add a class to `search-form` ?

Comment: CSS class or ES6 class?

Comment: CSS, for styling - I need to container (search-form) to have 100% width for example

Comment: @Yuvals you need to do that in the template where you *use* it: `<search-form class="full-width"></search-form>`, for example.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641281/how-to-add-class-to-host-element

Comment: What you tried is CSS that is applied to `<search-form>` but it is unrelated to "class".

Comment: Yes, I tried to refer also as "html" tag. Obviously this didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Component({ // or @Directive({
  // use `host:` or `@HostBinding()` (not both)
  // host: {'[class.someclass]': 'true'}
})
class SearchFormComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.someclass')
  someClass = true;
}
```

Perhaps you mean adding styles to "self" by adding this CSS to `search-form.component.css`

```
:host {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: What is the :host in this case? should I point to a child:host?

Comment: `:host` points to the component itself - the DOM element that hosts the component. From your question it's not clear to me what your problem actually is. If you provide more information, I might be able to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You declare CSS classes in your stylesheet .. search-form.component.css

If you want to target the component in your stylesheet then you could do ...

```
search-form {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

This will target elements with the tag search-form.

Because Angular2 is component based, it only targets elements inside the component. I am not sure if it will target the actual element itself but I think it will.

Answer (score -1):

I can show an example of this.

Firstly create a stylesheet. like

```
<style>
.red
{
color:red;
}
.blue
{
color:blue;
}
</style>
```

Then in your HTML include your style sheet along with angular.min.js and create a dropdown as below.

```
<select ng-model="a">
<option value="red">red</option>
<option value="blue">blue</option>

</select>
```

Then create a H1 tag like below.

```
<h1 ng-class="a">Header color</h1>
```

Note. HTML has to be within the div of ng-app you create.

Hope this helps. All the best.

Comment: The question is about Angular2. Your answer seems to be about AngularJS.