# angular default class for component

Tags: angular

How do you add a default CSS class to an angular component?

something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-slide-in-menu',
  templateUrl: './slide-in-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slide-in-menu.component.styl'],
  class: 'app-slide-in-menu'
})
```

But obviously `class` doesn't work

My desired result is that the component will be assigned the css class given on the topmost element within the component or on the component itself.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "class" to host element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641281/how-to-add-class-to-host-element)

Comment: Did you name your css-class on purpose "slide-in-menu.component.styl"? Shouldn't it end in '.css' or '.scss' instead of '.styl'? Is this maybe the problem you're facing?

Comment: no im using stylus but thanks :)

Comment: You could add a class to the template and override it in each individual components .styl file?

Comment: Why do you need the class? You can style app-slide-in-menu element directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:host{...} You can use :host to style the component

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the class without condition add this:

```js
HostBinding('class.yout-desired-class') yourClass = true;
```

Otherwise:

```js
HostBinding('class.yout-desired-class') yourClass = someCondition;
```