# CSS - Target a custom tag with wildcard?

Tags: html, css, angular

In my Angular application, I have components pages like `<app-page-home>`, `<app-page-login>`, `<app-page-documentation>`, etc. that are mounted when required in my `<router-outlet>`.

I am trying to target all these components together from a global stylesheet (`./src/styles.styl` that applies everywhere in the application), but CSS doesn't seem to accept wildcards for custom tags.

I would like to avoid listing my tags one by one and instead, something like `app-page-* { border : blue solid 1px; }`

```css
app-page-* {
   border : blue solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<app-page-login>Login stuff</app-page-login>
<br>
<app-page-documentation>Documentation</app-page-documentation>
```

I can't add classes (or can I?) because these component are being dynamically mounted by the router, otherwise I could obviously use something like `class="page"`.

Any idea how to target custom tags with a wild card? Thanks

Comment: This may work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641281/how-to-add-class-to-host-element

Comment: Thanks... Looks overkill... I'll just list my pages one by one, there are not too many of them

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, css doesn't have partial type wildcards. Most easy solution is to just group them together, like this;

```
app-page-login, app-page-documentation { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

Or apply a class to them;

```
<app-page-login class="app-page" />
<app-page-documentation class="app-page" />
```

and target the class;

```
.app-page { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

You could do fancy stuff with [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), but imo for your use case the two solutions above are the most suitable.

-- edit; I see you can't add classes. Use the first solution then.

Comment: That's what I thought, I guess I'll just have to list my tags one by one then :/