# ANGULAR add @HostBinding to all components

Tags: angular

I need to add some classes to host component conditionally.
it's simple:
add:

> @HostBinding('class.app-ltr') isLTR: boolean = true;

and change isLTR in the code;
but suppose I need 10 5 or 6 classes, then I need to add to all project components, it cause duplicated code.
what can I do?

I tried to create directive and append to component host, but this feature is not exist.
then I tried to create base component, but parent component doesn't effect.
then I tried to create custom decorator, but not success.

what is best practice?

Comment: check if this already answered post helps. I guess it covers maximum scenarios. Just have a look 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641281/how-to-add-class-to-host-element

Comment: as I said in my question, I know how to add class to host element, but I search for a solution to add class to all components, without duplicating code, your link just explain to add class to host element.